# Some elements which satisfy the condition in a two-dimensional array do not display

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array of floats, `arr[n][m]`, where the `n` defines the number of rows and `m` does the same for columns, the users enter them using the scanf() function. Each element is calculated according to the formula:

```
arr[i][j] = fabs(exp(i)-exp(j))+(i+j)/2.+1
```

I need to check if the element is less than the sum of its neigbours from the both sides (ignoring bottom and top in this case, but it would be nice to count them as well). It does count its number almost right, but for some reason it ignores the elements which are situated in the middle of the last two rows. Then I have to find the sum of such elements and replace them with the average of their neigbours' sum of indexes, counting i+j:

```
    for (i = 0; i<n; ++i, puts(" ")) // it's easier to deal with the elements displayed in this way
        for (j=1; j<m-1; ++j) // begin with the [0][1] because [0][0] doesn't have any neighbour on the left;
    m-1 because the last element does not have any neighbour on the right 
        {
            if (arr[i][j] < ((arr[i][j-1])+(arr[i][j+1])))
            {
                printf("%.2f  ", arr[i][j]);
                count++;
                sum+= arr[i][j];
                arr[i][j] = (i+j + i+j) / 4; 
            }
        }
    
        printf("\nThe number of such elements: %i", count);
        printf("\nThe sum of such elements is: %.2f", sum);
```

Therefore, the question is about counting the middle values in the last two rows and including them in the formula of sum.

[image]
I underlined the elements which satisfy the condition but do not display.

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: Because neither I nor my teacher do not mind resolving this on C++

Comment: @DaryaWiśniewski Kindly check the [C and C++ tag policies](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) for cross-posting questions using both tags. Scroll down to "Using c and c++ together".

Comment: C and C++ are distinct languages, with distinct "toolboxes" to solving a problem. A good C++ solution would look *significantly* different than your example; *not* pointing out where your example is not idiomatic C++ would do you a disservice. (`<vector>`, `<iostream>`, possibly `<algorithm>` and some lambdas...) But that's not what you are looking for; you are looking for the error in your **C** algorithm. So that's what your question should be tagged as.

Comment: Thank you, I'm a newbie, so further I'll be much more accurate with the tag of C++ due to the presented information

Comment: `for (i = 0; i<n; ++i, puts(" "))` - By the way, putting the `puts` here just to save a pair of braces is a really bad idea. Give the loop its own pair of braces (it's a good idea anyway), and put the `puts` after the inner loop as its own statement.

Comment: @DaryaWiśniewski: In case you are *learning* **C++**, have a word with your teacher... he [shouldn't put you through learning C first](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk), exactly *because* idiomatic C++ solutions look so different from what you'd do in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr[i][j] = (i+j + i+j) / 4;
```

What is this line for? You are replacing element values, mostly with much smaller values. That's why the comparison then fails - the element to the left is much smaller than it was, so the sum is no longer larger than the center element.

Comment: I need to do this, 'cause I've mentioned that I have to find the sum of such elements and replace them with the average of their neigbours' sum of indexes, counting i+j. I didn't think about this, so thanks a lot for the answer, now I do know how to deal with it

Comment: you should not replace them in the same matrix which you read in. This changes calculations for the following element. Create a new matrix with replacements instead.

Comment: Thank you, I got it from the Sebastian's comment :)